# Order of resolution for multiple awaits on one promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

If multiple tasks are waiting on a single promise, is there a guaranteed/specified by a standard order in which those tasks will begin executing once the promise is resolved? For example, consider the following

```
var promise = null;
function setPromiseIfNeeded() {
  if (!promise) {
    promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
  }
}
client.on('event1', event => {
  setPromiseIfNeeded();
  await promise;
  console.log('event 1 done awaiting');
}
client.on('event2', event => {
  setPromiseIfNeeded();
  await promise;
  console.log('event 2 done awaiting');
}
```

If `event1` occurs before `event2`, is it guaranteed that the handler for `event1` will awake from its promise before the handler for `event2`?

If the behavior is implementation dependent, I'm particularly curious about the behavior for node.js v12 and above.

Comment: This really smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The first one to call `setPromiseIfNeeded()` should be the first to do the log...however what is the actual higher level issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I have multiple event-driven tasks that each reach out to a web API that has global rate limits. If I am at the rate limit, I want to back off to avoid getting blocked. Rather than having each task separately calculate how long it needs to wait and have tons of promises, I thought it was more sensible to have the first task calculate the wait time, make a global promise, and have all the threads await it. But in that scenario, I want the thread that made the promise to wake up first so that it can properly clear the global promise state (although maybe that isn't necessary...)

Comment: @Alec The clearing of the global state should be done in the handler that also calls `resolve`, not in the "thread" that was waiting first. Btw, for rate-limiting I would recommend implementing an explicit queue

Comment: @Bergi Clearing state when you `resolve` makes a lot of sense - I hadn't thought of that possibility! As for the explicit queue, that's more or less what's happening under the hood, it's just complicated by there being both per-route and global (all routes) rate limits, so it can't all go in a single queue :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed. Promise handlers (`then` callbacks) are run in the same order in which they were installed on the promise (`.then()` call). This translates into the same for `await` syntax.